# Fragment shows blank white Screen

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm facing a strange problem and totally clueless about what is causing the problem.

I have one Mainactivity with pager layout where Tabs Contain two tabs "Sec A " and "Sec B".
Under Sec A and Sec B, I have another fragment with pager layout and now each contain seven Days of week to show the Time Table of Class of our university.

Now, The Problem is When app launch for first Time, If I load Sec A fragment , then it loads and fill the child fragment of seven days very well but when I click Sec B tab...then all the seven days of Sec B show white screen although I have used same layout file , database and adapter class for Both Sec A and B. If instead I load Sec B then Sec B loads but Sec A shows white screen now.

Here is the link for my whole project https://github.com/BlueYeti1881/routine

My project File Structure is 
[image]

My Sec A Fragment is 
[image]

and Sec B Fragment is

[image]

My Sec A Fragment class is

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_section, container, false);



        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager_dayscount);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());

            adapter.addFragment(new sunA(), "Sun");
        adapter.addFragment(new monA(), "Mon");
         adapter.addFragment(new tueA(), "Tue");
        adapter.addFragment(new wedA(), "Wed");
         adapter.addFragment(new thuA(), "Thu");
        adapter.addFragment(new friA(), "Fri");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs_dayscount);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


        return view;
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

which is same as B and my Adapter class is

```
public class AmonAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AmonAdapter.Holder> {

    private static final String TAG = AmonAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private final FlowerClickListener mListener;
    private List<Flower> mFlowers;

    public AmonAdapter(FlowerClickListener listener) {
        mFlowers = new ArrayList<>();
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View row = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.days_item, null, false);
        return new Holder(row);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {

        Flower currFlower = mFlowers.get(position);

        holder.mName.setText(currFlower.getName());
        holder.mPrice.setText(String.format("$%.2f", currFlower.getPrice()));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFlowers.size();
    }

    public void addFlower(Flower flower) {
        mFlowers.add(flower);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



    public void reset() {
        mFlowers.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

 private TextView mName, mPrice;

        public Holder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flowerName);
            mPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flowerPrice);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.onClick(getLayoutPosition());
        }
    }

    public interface FlowerClickListener {

        void onClick(int position);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think second time view pager giving null, check that one bro..

Comment: @Vijaykumar yes vijay I checked on logcat ..and yes it give me null but why..I experimented with puttting sec A and Sec B in two different activity ...and switch between two from menu and it works but when I use the same switch function with Fragment

Comment: `List<Fragment>` should be list not a `Fragment`. Is there  any logcat errors that we can see?

Comment: @BirNepali change title of tabs on secB like SUN-B,MON-B etc.. then we can understand problem from tabs or either fragments

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท since the app donot crash .it just only shows white screen when I select secB, so I could manage only this https://ibb.co/hYKsZz if there is anything I'll provide you. here is the link to whole project https://github.com/BlueYeti1881/routine

Comment: @Vijaykumar Ok vijay I'll just do that just give me a minute